# Soda CLI show warning : Migrator: unable to dump schema: exec: "pg_dump": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, database-migration, buffalo

I'm new on using gobuffalo, and every time i run migrate always show this warning. What is the meaning of that warning?

```
> soda migrate up
v5.3.1

[POP] 2021/05/25 14:17:12 info - > create_products
[POP] 2021/05/25 14:17:12 info - Successfully applied 1 migrations.
[POP] 2021/05/25 14:17:12 info - 0.0829 seconds
[POP] 2021/05/25 14:17:12 warn - Migrator: unable to dump schema: exec: "pg_dump": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Is there something wrong in my server or this warning not effect anything? any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the `soda` CLI for executing the migrations, `soda` applies the migrations, then it tries to dump the current database schema using the database native tool.

This warning only says the `pg_dump` executable was not found on your server, and soda couldn't dump the current schema. Since the migrations run fine, you can safely ignore this warning.

Comment: ignoring the warning isn't the solution for the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I just added in PATH variable location to PostgreSQL/bin directory.
For example how PATH variable can be change in Windows can be found:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

For me it solved the issue.